# Item '/sitecore/media library' does not contain IntegrationConfigData field

Tags: site-configuration

I am getting several exceptions on the CMS Master server, such as the one shown below.

```
ManagedPoolThread #17 2016:10:25 08:23:54 ERROR Synchronization context can not be created for "media library" integration config data source item.
Exception: System.Exception
Message: Item "/sitecore/media library" does not contain IntegrationConfigData field.
Source: Sitecore.Sharepoint.Data.Providers
   at Sitecore.Sharepoint.Data.Providers.IntegrationConfig.IntegrationConfigDataProvider.ValidateIntegrationItem(Item targetIntegrationItem)
   at Sitecore.Sharepoint.Data.Providers.IntegrationConfig.IntegrationConfigDataProvider.GetFromItem(Item sourceIntegrationItem)
   at Sitecore.Sharepoint.Data.Providers.SynchContext.Initialize()
   at Sitecore.Sharepoint.Data.Providers.SharepointProvider.ProcessTree(ProcessIntegrationItemsOptions processIntegrationItemsOptions, Item integrationConfigDataSource)
```

My Sitecore CMS is version 7.0  I have separate Master Server and Content Delivery servers configured as well.

I have SharePoint integration with Sitecore setup.

Any ideas what could be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first port of call, I would try reinstalling the SharePoint module.

From the [docs](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi054Hbg5zQAhUHLsAKHdOKCKQQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.sitecore.net%2F~%2Fmedia%2FAB096C2A149342538194D3572AAD8071.ashx&usg=AFQjCNGQko-p2JTdK8f0eIO-Tbcbnc6OtQ) I would check that the "Sharepoint Integration Configuration" template exists:

> To integrate SharePoint lists with the Sitecore content tree or the
>   Media Library use the SharePoint Integration wizard to create a
>   SharePoint integration definition item based on the SharePoint
>   Integration Configuration template. You can find the SharePoint
>   Integration Configuration template at the following location:
>   /sitecore/templates/Sharepoint/Item Level Integration/Sharepoint
>   Integration Configuration

It sounds like the field referenced should exist on the items being called. Check that this field exists - I believe it's needed for Item Level Configuration:

> SPIF determines which configuration to use using the following
>   prioritization:
>   1. It checks whether there is an alternative configuration. For item-level integration, the configuration is in the Integration
>   Configuration Data field of the Integration Definition item. For more
>   information about configuration for item-level integration, see
>   section Editing the XML in a SharePoint Integration Definition Item.
>   2. If there are no alternative configuration details, SPIF checks for predefined configuration details in the sharepoint.config file.
>   3. If there are no predefined configuration details, it uses the default configuration details.

Also, can you open the Sharepoint Integration Wizard? From there you should be able to check that you don't have incorrectly assigned templates and field mappings.